# Why can't we use conservation of angular momentum to solve this question since this whole system is isolated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, torque

A solid rubber wheel of radius $R$ and mass $M$ rotates with angular velocity $\omega_0$ about a frictionless pivot. A second rubber wheel of radius $r$ and mass $m$ also mounted on a frictionless pivot is brought into contact with it. What is the final angular velocity of the first wheel?

Answer (score 1):

The system is not isolated. The frictionless pivots can exert forces on the system, and since they are not co-axial those forces will generate a net torque about any axis.

Comment: Thanks sir. Thinking again and again about this question made me realize my mistake.